# Vaadin 8 NativeSelect change data representation of list

Tags: drop-down-menu, kotlin, vaadin, selection, vaadin8

I am using Vaadin 8 `NativeSelect` as a dropdown for users to make selections. Each selection refers to an object instance that holds multiple pieces of data and I only want the dropdown to display one piece of identifying information pertaining to a single variable in that object however it doesn't seem like `NativeSelect` can handle Model and Presentation separately in an obvious way.

```
data class Consultant(
    val name: String,
    val id: Long
)

val consultantSelection = NativeSelect<Consultant>().apply { 
    setItems(consultantDao.getAll())
    caption = "Select Consultant"
}
```

In my code, I create a `NativeSelect` handling a type of `Consultant` which then creates a dropdown menu that simply unpacks the contents of the respective `Consultant` objects as each selectable. I would like to only display the `name` of the `Consultant` in the selection.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a [`setItemCaptionGenerator`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.5/com/vaadin/ui/NativeSelect.html#setItemCaptionGenerator-com.vaadin.ui.ItemCaptionGenerator-) for this.  Otherwise Vaadin falls back to the `.toString()` implementation.

There is a whole section about dealing with things around that in [Vaadin Documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-selection.html#components.selection)